# Dependencies between classes in simple Windows Forms game

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, dependencies, concept

I have conceptual problem with organizing clesses in my simple Windows Forms based game project. I have to implement [Whack-A-Mole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whac-A-Mole) game using Windows Forms. Molehills are represented by checkoxes. If checkbox is checked then there is a mole in the molehill. Mole can be killed by clicking checked checkbox.

I managed to create `GamePlay` class which contains i.a. classes: `GameBoard` (game board representation based on `TableLayoutPanel` and array of checkboxes), `Rules` (propability rates, max number of moles during one round, round's duration and so on). In `GamePlay` class there is also `PointsCounter` (how many moles have been killed so far). There are more classes/structures in my solution but they are not important in context of this problem.

Size of game board can be set in configuration window so I create checkboxes on *TableLayoutPanel* dynamically, after clicking *Start Game* button. Array of checkboxes and event handler for them are placed in `GameBoard` class. After mole's killing I have to update (actually I have to add proper value called `pointsForMoleKilling` from `Rules` class). But I can't in such a classes model. There is no access to `PointsCounter` (which is in `GamePlay` class) from event handler *checkbox mouse click* (which is in `GameBoard` class).

How should I reorganize dependencies between classes?
My temporary solution is to make `Rules`, `pointsForMoleKilling` and `score()` (also from `GamePlay` class) **static**.

Answer (score 1):

I think you and Peekay's answer are backwards.  Your `GameBoard` is a view (a particular representation of the state of the game) and should not depend directly on the `GamePlay` class, which sounds awfully like a controller class.  You should also not mix the concept of the game model with the view of that model (which you appear to be doing in `GameBoard`).  I would suggest you review the MVC pattern.

Consider what elements you would want to persist to disk if a user wanted to save their game half-way through.  You would probably need to save the `rules` for that particular game, the `score`, the current `time`, and the state of the `board`.  These things are your model: `GameModel` has `rules`, `score`, `time`, and `state`.

Now... you want to be able to display this model to the user in some form of visual representation.  This is known as a view.  A `GameView` displays your `GameModel` using Windows Forms.  It probably does this by displaying the score with a `ScoreView`, the time with a `TimeView`, and the board with a `BoardView` or some other separation.

Finally, you need to respond to UI events (such as mole whacks, or pausing/exiting the game).  This class is responsible for subscribing to UI events, and processing those events by updating the model.  It is known as a controller.

Making a class static for the reason of making its state global is generally not the best idea in OO-world.

Comment: But if I would keep state of game board in `state` class (there are molehills represented by checkboxes) how I would subscribe event handlers (for instance ckeckbox click event handler) from controller class? I don't understand how we can subscribe event handler from controller-class to checkbox-click event from `state` class. In my opinion there is no access unless we make event handlers from controller-class `static`.

Comment: Your controller class is responsible for handling UI events and updating your model.  So one way to do this would be for your controller to register to click events, and then update your state.  The whack-a-mole game doesn't have any concept of a "checkbox" only of molehills and whacks, so your state shouldn't know about checkboxes or clicks.  `View -> Fires Click Event -> Controller -> Calls Whack() method -> Model`

Answer (score 0):

I've found great way to design classes dependencies in C# (using XNA) simple game.
It's kind of template. It's called **Game State Management** and it's very similar to **[ungood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559492/ungood)**'s concept.

More details:

- [create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management)
- [nazspace.com/wp/2008/02/04/using-the-game-state-management-sample](http://www.nazspace.com/wp/2008/02/04/using-the-game-state-management-sample/)